# My margin is not working for h3 when I tried adding space

Tags: html, css

My margin for `<h3>` is not working.
I wanted to add some space in between the form and the `h3`

css:

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.8),rgba(0,0,0,0.8)),url(/assets/1.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.container{
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    min-height: 400px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 8% auto;
    background: #f3f6f7;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

h3{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    color: #333;
}

.container form{
    width: 280px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

form input{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <h2>Let's Start Building!</h2>
        <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" required>

    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: H2 in HTML vs. H3 in CSS

Comment: first of all welcome to stack overflow, Please check obvious things like if h3 is there in the html first, to be sure there is an issue. Also once you update and if the issue is still there feel free to edit the question and leave a comment here.

Comment: OOhhhh... I'm new to it
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML heading element is a `h2` element and you're attempting to style a `h3`
heading element.